# HTML5 pattern not working

Tags: regex, html

I am trying to give a pattern for Mobile field. Here is my code:

```
<form id="regr" name="regr" action="#" method="get">
    <table style="padding-top: 25px;">    
     <tr style="height: 40px;">
      <td style="text-align:right;">Mobile:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="mobNum" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" title="XXX-XXX-XXXX"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Register" name="Register" onclick="sessionstore()"/>
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" onclick="window.location.reload()"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

I have different fields below and above the Mobile field. Everything is inside a form tag. When I click on Submit, the pattern mentioned above is not validating. I can enter even alphabets and still able to save. Please advice on what is wrong here. Thanks.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Ensure that your browser supports the `pattern` attribute. Also could you show us that this is indeed inside a `<form>`?

Comment: is it in a form? how is it being submitted? Not really enough information given

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nx5wjv0y/1/ Can't reproduce the problem in newest Firefox/Chrome, on Win... Maybe you are on Mac (Safari)? http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern

Comment: Why is there no name attribute on the input?

Comment: does it help to set the type of the register-button to "submit"?